# Extract pixel values using pixel condition in R

Tags: r, extract, data-frame

I am preparing a dataset to run a SVM classification. So far, I have a raster stack  which includes a layer (`[6]`) for training

```
> S1
class       : RasterStack 
dimensions  : 3865, 6899, 26664635, 6  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 14.83, 14.83  (x, y)
extent      : 361363.5, 463675.7, 5760647, 5817965  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
names       : Coherence_VV_Stack2.1, Coherence_VV_Stack2.2, Coherence_VV_Stack2.3, Coherence_VV_Stack2.4, Coherence_VV_Stack2.5, Class 
min values  :                     ?,                     ?,                     ?,                     ?,                     ?,     0 
max values  :                     ?,                     ?,                     ?,                     ?,                     ?,     1
```

Where `S1[[6]]` is:

```
> S1[[6]]
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 3865, 6899, 26664635  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 14.83, 14.83  (x, y)
extent      : 361363.5, 463675.7, 5760647, 5817965  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : Class 
values      : 0, 1  (min, max)
```

and `plot(S1[[6])` is:

[image]

I want to create a `dataframe` (to be used later as input for classification) where:

- If pixel value in `S1[[6]]` is `1`, extract the pixel values in the other layers of the `raster stack` and put it in the `dataframe`
- If pixel value in `S1[[6]]` is`0`, do nothing.

Any suggestion on how to proceed? I know the issue can be solved by importing a `shapefile` and use the `extract` function but I want to use this approach.

Comment: What columns do you want in your data frame?

Answer (score 1):

Given a 3x4 cell x 6 layer brick where the last layer is a 0/1 indicator:

```
> S1
class       : RasterBrick 
dimensions  : 3, 4, 12, 6  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 0.25, 0.3333333  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
data source : in memory
names       :    layer.1,    layer.2,    layer.3,    layer.4,    layer.5,    layer.6 
min values  : 0.07979194, 0.01004478, 0.12462376, 0.08388173, 0.03662221, 0.00000000 
max values  :  0.8417125,  0.9823274,  0.9087239,  0.9050184,  0.9624438,  1.0000000
```

Then this one-liner will return a data frame of the values in the first five layers for cells that have a one in the last layer:

```
> ones = setNames(do.call(cbind.data.frame,
          lapply(1:nlayers(S1),
                 function(i){S1[[i]][S1[[nlayers(S1)]][]==1]})),
                 names(S1))
> ones
     layer.1    layer.2   layer.3    layer.4    layer.5 layer.6
1 0.61572701 0.30333021 0.4982907 0.18118309 0.03662221       1
2 0.84171251 0.98232742 0.1246238 0.40075522 0.68438716       1
3 0.37735819 0.27628720 0.7060747 0.25431005 0.33987833       1
4 0.30291850 0.10383452 0.2485474 0.90501841 0.30548540       1
5 0.57979692 0.01196571 0.4019636 0.36540125 0.96244376       1
6 0.14576374 0.48495665 0.4268066 0.34438584 0.83443135       1
7 0.70245897 0.01004478 0.9087239 0.78135612 0.19428952       1
8 0.79984520 0.24450234 0.1956386 0.08388173 0.07563230       1
9 0.07979194 0.32003334 0.3989493 0.48715195 0.18219895       1
```

To check, the first column should be the numbers in here:

```
> as.matrix(S1[[1]])
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]       [,4]
[1,] 0.6157270 0.8417125 0.3773582 0.30291850
[2,] 0.5797969 0.1457637 0.3296398 0.46653010
[3,] 0.7024590 0.7198337 0.7998452 0.07979194
```

that have a one in here:

```
> as.matrix(S1[[6]])
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    0    0
[3,]    1    0    1    1
```

Building tiny examples is a very useful skill when developing data analysis methods.

Comment: What if I want to extract the values when `S1[[6]]` is `1` AND `0`. Would it be something like `S1[[6]]==1&&0` or `S1[[6]]==1 && S1[[6]]==0`?

Comment: A single value in `S1[[6]]` can't be both 1 AND 0 - you need a conditional `OR` test. `z = c(0, 1, 2, NA)` then `(z == 1) | (z == 0)`. Might want to create the function outside the one-liner for testing purposes.